# Create an extension to the browser to acces local scanner

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I would like to access a special hardware (a penta scanner, for the wisest ;) ) from a web page.
The aim is to retrieve the information from the scanner and compute it on server side.

The problem here, is that I have to summon functions from a DLL that **has to be** on the client side. I have two leads for that:

- Develop a COM DLL and use ActiveX
- Try to get through a homemade extension for a web browser in order to communicate with the local DLLs.

I've tried the first option, and I got stuck and I've posted another thread about it. Anyway, even if it works, there are too many constraints about it (as to use IE or the fact that even Microsoft is not fond of this feature and banned it from edge).

The second method is something that I found on another forum but, I do not understand how I can interact with a browser extension (whatever the browser).
So what I am asking is:

Is it possible to use a web browser extension as a medium to a local DLL and if so, would you be so kind as to give a hint about how to do ar anything that might look like a start about how to do it (even just some key words to use on google, since mine didn't get anything)....

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, the motive to develop an Extensions is to enhance the feature and functionality for particular web browser.

You cannot control any hardware devices like printer or scanner with it.

So if your goal is to control the scanner from your web page with the help of any kind of extension than I think you cannot do this with Extension.